# Can you add widgets to SageMaker Notebooks similar to Azure DataBricks?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, azure-databricks, amazon-sagemaker

I have used Azure DataBricks in my earlier job and it comes with extended support for Notebook widgets to execute notebook manually/ commission a notebook job by selecting some values (Ideally your run state params or variables.)

For information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/widgets

Is there a similar service or option that I can build while working on SageMaker notebooks?

Answer (score 0):

From Sagemaker Notebook Instances select ‘Open Jupyter’

In Jupyter select the Nbextensions tab

Uncheck the box ‘disable configurations for nbextensions…’

Open Jupyterlab -> Now the UI widgets work in Jupyterlab

Refer - https://forums.fast.ai/t/ipywidgets-not-displaying-on-aws-sagemaker-fastai/85039